# How to set a SourceRange for multiple columns in xls?

Tags: excel, vba, consolidation

I am trying to consolidate a data from multiple worksheets into one, using a master spreadsheet.

However, it seems that I can only set a sourceRange for consecutive columns and I would like to copy different columns (e.g. A, C and K).

Can someone please help with a command how to do this? Also I would like the whole column to be copied as long as it has data (rather than specifying the cell range), anyone knows how this can be done?

This is the code I'm using (found online):

```
Sub MergeAllDeliverables()
    Dim SummarySheet As Worksheet
    Dim FolderPath As String
    Dim NRow As Long
    Dim Filename As String
    Dim WorkBk As Workbook
    Dim SourceRange As Range
    Dim DestRange As Range



' Create a new workbook and set a variable to the first sheet.
Set SummarySheet = Workbooks.Add(xlWBATWorksheet).Worksheets(1)


' Modify this folder path to point to the files you want to use.
FolderPath = "C:\Users\..."

' NRow keeps track of where to insert new rows in the destination workbook.
NRow = 1

' Call Dir the first time, pointing it to all Excel files in the folder path.
Filename = Dir(FolderPath & "*.xl*")

' Loop until Dir returns an empty string.
Do While Filename <> ""
    ' Open a workbook in the folder
    Set WorkBk = Workbooks.Open(FolderPath & Filename)

    ' Set the cell in column A to be the file name.
    SummarySheet.Range("A" & NRow).Value = Filename


    ' Set the source range to be what you like.
    ' Modify this range for your workbooks.
    ' It can span multiple rows.
    Set SourceRange = WorkBk.Worksheets(1).Range("a:1")




    ' Set the destination range to start at column B and
    ' be the same size as the source range.
    Set DestRange = SummarySheet.Range("B" & NRow)
    Set DestRange = DestRange.Resize(SourceRange.Rows.Count, _
       SourceRange.Columns.Count)

    ' Copy over the values from the source to the destination.
    DestRange.Value = SourceRange.Value

    ' Increase NRow so that we know where to copy data next.
    NRow = NRow + DestRange.Rows.Count

    ' Close the source workbook without saving changes.
    WorkBk.Close savechanges:=False

    ' Use Dir to get the next file name.
    Filename = Dir()
Loop

' Call AutoFit on the destination sheet so that all
' data is readable.
   SummarySheet.Columns.AutoFit

End Sub
```

Comment: Try the `Union` method.  You could also look at `Range.Consolidate` method.  If neither does what you want, post examples of your input and desired output, and tell us the problem precisely.  Please post text and not screenshots, as it is difficult to copy a screenshot into an Excel sheet to replicate your problem.

Answer (score 1):

With **.Range()** you can set multiple columns - like:

```
Dim rng As Range
Set rng = Sheets(1).Range("A1:A100, D3:D400")
```

Instead of specifying this exactly:

```
Dim rng As Range
Dim lastRow As Long, lastColumn As Long

For i = 1 To Rows.Count - 1

    If IsEmpty(Cells(i, 1)) Then Exit For

Next i

Set rng = Range("A1:A" & i)
```

The **1** in **Cells(i, 1)** is for the first column **A**.

For every column you could create a For-Loop for counting the filled cells.

If there are empty cells between filled cells in a column - you've to go another way (answer of user...) :)

An example for column **A** and **D**:

```
For i = 1 To Rows.Count - 1

    If IsEmpty(Cells(i, 1).Value) Then Exit For

Next i

For j = 1 To Rows.Count - 1

    If IsEmpty(Cells(j, 4).Value) Then Exit For

Next j

Set rng = Range("A1:A" & i & ", D1:D" & j)
```

Comment: `Range("A1:A100", "D3:D400")` **is NOT** a "multiple columns" range, while it refers to a range whose upper-left cell is the most upper-left cell of the two ranges and whose lower-right cell is the most lower-right cell of the two ranges: i.e. it results in $A$1:$D$400 .  to have a real "multiple columns" range you must enclose commas inside quotes like `Range("A1:A100, D3:D400")`.  Moreover counting filled cells as you propose would miss all cells following the first _hole_ (blank cells preceded and followed by non blank ones) in a column

Comment: @user3598756 - thanks. Didn't know this :) I'll change my answer a bit.

Answer (score 1):

you can set a "multiple columns" range like follows

```
Set multiColRng = Range("C:C, G:H, K")
```

but

- pasting values of entire columns can be time consuming (and useless)
- columns can have "holes", i.e. blank cells between their first and last non blank cells

so it'd be useful to paste only non blank values of a "multiple columns" range

this brings in the issue of the [`Areas`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff196243%28v=office.15%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396) property of `Range` object which is both the solution (you *have* to pass through it)  and the concern (it's a little *tricky*, at least it *is* to me) of the goal

you may then want to use the following sub:

```
Option Explicit

Sub PasteColumnsValues(multiColsRng As Range, destRng As Range)
    Dim col As Long, row As Long, colsArea As Long, rowsArea As Long

    With multiColsRng.Areas '<~~ consider "columns" areas in which columns range is divided
        For colsArea = 1 To .count '<~~ loop through those "column" areas
            With .Item(colsArea) '<~~ consider current "column" area
                For col = 1 To .Columns.count '<~~ loop through all "real" (single) columns of which a single "column" area consists of
                    row = 1 '<~~ initialize pasting row index
                    With .Columns.Item(col).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeConstants, xlNumbers) '<~~ consider current "real" (single) column
                        For rowsArea = 1 To .Areas.count '<~~ loop through all areas of which a single "real" column consists of
                            With .Areas(rowsArea) '<~~ consider current area of the current "real" (single) column
                                destRng(row, colsArea + col - 1).Resize(.count).Value = .Value '<~~ paste current area values
                                row = row + .Rows.count '<~~ update pasting row index
                            End With
                        Next rowsArea
                    End With
                Next col
            End With
        Next colsArea
    End With
End Sub
```

which can be used as follows:

```
Sub main()
    With ActiveSheet
        PasteColumnsValues Range("C:C, G:H"), .Range("N1") '<~~ the 1st argument MUST be a "multiple column" Range
    End With
End Sub
```